# Substring outofindex

Tags: c#, string

I wrote a code for which

if 23E+20 is the input then output should be 230000000(20 zeros)

if 4.456E-14 is the input then 4.456000(14 zeros) should be the output

But its not working properly.
Please let me know where I did error.
Thank You.

```
using System;

class test

{

public static void Main()

{

Console.WriteLine("Enter double");

      String ext =Console.ReadLine();



           if(ext.IndexOf("E")!=-1)
        {
           int i=ext.IndexOf("E");

          ext = ext.Substring(0, i);

          for (int j = 0; j < int.Parse(ext.Substring(i + 1, ext.Length - (i + 1))); j++)

          ext = ext + "0";         

          Console.WriteLine(ext);



      }

}   

Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

Comment: Output for 4.456E-14 isn't 4.456000(14 zeros).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you substring ext in 
ext = ext.Substring(0,i)
you are assigning ext = "4.456" and cutting away the e-part

when you do  ext.Length - (i + 1) in the for loop you get a negative index

Try this instead

```
int noZeroes = Int32.Parse(ext.Substring(i + 1))
ext = ext.Substring(0, i);
string zeroString = new string('0', noZeroes)

ext += zeroString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going out of bounds of the string, remember always use i-1 index for last letter of array of size i(assuming arrays that start at 0 which is what most languages use).
Although it just an educated guess as I don't know C#.

Comment: Also the for loop plus the if (ext.Substring(i, 1) == "E")
looks weird isn't there some standard string function that returns the start of a match of a substring?

Comment: ya, I know, Array or string, their index starts from zero.
That's why I wrote
i<length
instead of i<=length

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: If very big values are multiplied or divided then we get results like 23E+20 , 4.456E-14
I need to make these user understandable

Comment: Also whats with all the looping, couldn't you at least loop i till you find E then break and loop j((nested loops aren't good even if they do only a simple comparison each time). Why aren't you using IndexOf then, are you trying to allow numbers like 12E+10E+30?

Comment: I think the other poster is right and string.Format("{?:?}",number) is probably what you want, I'm not sure which one it is the right format, you could try 0 0 like he said.
See 
http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/ for more details

Comment: I Tried. It's printing Input as it is.

Comment: That link is Very Useful.
Thank You.

Comment: turns out you have to convert the string to a number like 

        String str2=String.Format("{0:0}",Convert.ToInt32(str1));
if you leave it a string it ignores numerical formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simpler solution to your problem:

```
String s = Console.ReadLine();
Double d = Double.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.#############################################################################"));
```